# Compute the derivative of a 3D regular grid data after interpolation

Tags: python, numpy, scipy, interpolation, h5py

My data is a regular 3D grid and as an easiest example I have given here the code of a simple h5 file for a simple cube and I use `RegularGridInterpolator` function to interpolate. But, I want to know how can I change my code so that, I can get derivative from this interpolated function? For your kind information, I have given here my code:

code for generating h5 file:

```
import numpy as np
import h5py

def f(x,y,z):
   return 2 * x**3 + 3 * y**2 - z

x = np.linspace(-1, 1, 2)
y = np.linspace(-1, 1, 2)
z = np.linspace(-1, 1, 2)
mesh_data = f(*np.meshgrid(x, y, z, indexing='ij', sparse=True))

h5file = h5py.File('cube.h5', 'w')
h5file.create_dataset('/x', data=x)
h5file.create_dataset('/y', data=y)
h5file.create_dataset('/z', data=z)
h5file.create_dataset('/mesh_data', data=mesh_data)

h5file.close()
```

Code for interpolation:

```
import numpy as np   
import h5py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from mpl_toolkits.mplot3d import Axes3D
from scipy.interpolate import RegularGridInterpolator
from mpl_toolkits.mplot3d.art3d import Poly3DCollection, Line3DCollection
f = h5py.File('cube.h5', 'r')  #importing h5 file from gevolution output
list(f.keys())
dset = f[u'mesh_data']
dset.shape
dset.value.shape
dset[0:2,0:2,0:2]
x = np.linspace(-1, 1, 2)
y = np.linspace(-1, 1, 2)
z = np.linspace(-1, 1, 2)
def deriv_interp(x, y, z, dset):
    d_dset = np.gradient(dset)
    deriv_interpolators = [RegularGridInterpolator((x, y, z), d, method = 'linear') for d in d_dset]
    def interp(x,y,z):
        return np.dstack([d(x,y,z) for d in deriv_interpolators])
    return interp
pts = np.array([0.2, 0.9, 0.6]) 
deriv_interpolators(pts)
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't think `RegularGridInterpolator` has any helpful attribute for finding the derivative, as it can only do linear or nearest neighbors interpolation so it's not really creating aything derivative-like under the hood. You'd need some sort of n-d polynomial interpolator which doesn't seem to be implemented in `scipy` as far as I can see.  Of course you could always just use [`np.gradient`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.15.0/reference/generated/numpy.gradient.html) on your gridded data, and then make another set of iterpolators for each dimension.

```
def deriv_interp(x, y, z, dset):
    d_dset = np.gradient(dset)
    deriv_interpolators = [RegularGridInterpolator((x, y, z), d, method = 'linear') for d in d_dset]
    def interp(coord):
        return np.dstack([d(coord) for d in deriv_interpolators])
    return interp
```

Haven't really checked that, but that should be the general idea.

Comment: According to your suggestion, I have changed my code and edited my question (please see the second code in the question portion entitled 'code for interpolation' ). Can you please help me to find out my mistakes here? @Daniel

Answer (score 0):

Not 100% sure what your are trying to achieve and maybe you have already tried something like this, but what about:

```
import jax
finterp=RegularGridInterpolator((x, y, z), meshdata, method = 'linear')
gradf=jax.grad(finterp)
```

Or you could try:

```
gradf=jax.grad(f)
```